# TypeError. I don't understand what the error is

Tags: python, typeerror

I made a program that I designed to be able to read or write a file given that files directory. I made the read function and when I tested it out I was given this error

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found
```

The code is:

```
def file():
    dir = raw_input("DIR : ")
def read():
    f = open(dir, "r")
    for line in f:
        print line.strip("\n")
    f.close
def main():
    file()
    op = raw_input("ACTION : ")
    if op == "read":
        read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It says the error is in the line:

```
f = open(dir, "r")
```

Also if someone could suggest what I could add to be able to write to a file

Comment: The file() function sets a local variable "dir", then throws it away.  The "dir" in your open is the <built-in function dir>, not your variable.  If you want to pass values that way, add "global dir" to the top of each function.

Comment: So a variable needs to have "global" before it if it's going to be used in more than the function it's wrote in?

Comment: variables that are modified or created within a function (which is the case for `dir` in `file()`) are always considered local to that function unless you manually specify them as global.

Comment: Rather than using a global variable, which you should almost never do, you should return a value from your function.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules). The problem is that the function `read` does not know about the variable `dir`. Usually, this would lead to a `NameError`, but in this case, `dir` is also the name of a builtin function. It's this function that gets passed to the `open` call which causes the seen error. You should take the directory name as an argument to the `read` function. And in general, you should avoid names that clash with builtins.

Answer (score 1):

Globals as suggseted by swstephe are a generally bad idea and should be avoided as much as possible. 
Prefer using arguments:

```
def file():
    dir = raw_input("DIR : ")
    return dir
def read(dir):
    f = open(dir, "r")
    for line in f:
        print line.strip("\n")
    f.close
def main():
    dir = file()
    op = raw_input("ACTION : ")
    if op == "read":
        read(dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems in your code, but the `TypeError` is because `dir` isn't what you think it is.  [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is a python builtin function.

Presumably, you think that because `dir` got set in the `file` function that it will continue to be set in the `read` function.  This isn't true.  Python variables have a scope -- They (usually) only live in the function/module/... where they are defined<sup>1</sup>.  The best way for a function to pass data to the caller is to `return` the value.  Then you can pass that value on to other functions using arguments.  Some minimal modifications that I would make to your code would look like this:

```
def file():
    return raw_input("DIR : ")

def read(dir):
    f = open(dir, "r")
    for line in f:
        print line.strip("\n")
    f.close()

def main():
    dir = file()
    op = raw_input("ACTION : ")
    if op == "read":
        read(dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There are more changes that could be made here (change the names `dir` and `file` to avoid conflicts with builtins, use a context manager for the file resource management, etc.), but this should at least get you started.

<sup><sup>1</sup>There are also closures and the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords which make things more difficult, but they aren't super relevant for this answer, so I'm going to gloss over that detail ...</sup>